# How to write a C++ Console-Window Program

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, console-application, wxwidgets

I want to write a C++ program such that according to a config file can be a Console application or Window application. For GUI I'm using WxWidget. What should I do in Windows and Linux (Buntu) separately.

Can someone provide some simple example?

Comment: I'm confused, all C++ programs should run via console by default. What are you asking?

Comment: By Console app, I mean a program which has main() function and By Win-App I mean a GUI without any main function and a one which brings up a window form like any WxWidget program.

Comment: Why can't you simply write the whole program with a `WinMain()` method instead of `main()`? If you do not want to draw the GUI at this point, then don't and simply update the console. Otherwise, draw the GUI and hide the console.

Comment: I don't want to have both, I would like to have a config file such that it enables me to compile code in console-or-window style without changing the code later. For example, I be able to compile it on a linux server without any graphic library with just changing config file.

Comment: In Windows, /SUBSYSTEM linker flag defines, whether application has a console window. AFAIK, in Linux any application may be executed inside a terminal or without it, so this doesn't depend on an application itself.

Comment: To clarify what @AlexFarber said: It is **impossible** on Windows to create a program that determines its subsystem after it has already started running. If you need to support the console, then use `main` and then call `FreeConsole` to hide the console when you determine you should be running a GUI instead. The console still pops up, but there's no way around it.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Do you want the config file to control how the application is compiled, that is the config is read when the build starts, or how the application runs, that is when the application itself starts to run.

Comment: Thanks for the good Ideas. @Mehrdad: Is that possible to run GUI when we start from Console-app (when I specified /subsystem as console)?

Comment: @Ravenspoint: I want to have both abilities. How I can do it when config file is going to control compilation?

Comment: @Mehrdad: One common workaround is to have your code in a dll, and then have a .exe with the GUI subsystem, and a .com be the console subsystem.  If you type `myapp` in the console, it'll use the .com, and then make GUI shortcuts point to the exe.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in the compilation stage is straightforward using conditional compilation.

Your configuration file will contain the preprocessor difinitions you want.  For example

```
#define GUI
```

or

```
#define CONSOLE
```

Then you include the config file in each file you want to compile differently

```
#include "gui_or_console.h"
```

Lastly, you use the conditional compile to tell the compiler which code to process

```
#idfef GUI

  // some GUI code

#endif

#ifdef CONSOLE

 // some CONSOLE code

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do this at runtime is to compile and link your program as a Windows application.  At run-time you read the config.  If it's set for GUI, then create windows and be on your way.  If it's set for console mode, then you can create a console window, attach your stdout/stdin/sterr streams to it, and off you go.

I've written one program that runs like this.  The entire UI is abstracted behind a pure-virtual interface, and the concrete implementations provide a console implementation and a GUI implementation.  At runtime, I instantiate the correct type.  The constructor makes the right type of window.  The main program then calls a virtual Run method.  The console implementation calls the equivalent of main.  The GUI implementation runs an event loop.

The really hard part is to attach to the existing console window if you're launched from the command line of one (rather than starting up your own console window).  Devstudio does this by having a devstudio.com and devstudio.exe, but it's rather involved.